# How to deploy code from Visual Studio to Cosmos triggers on change

Tags: javascript, c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have a visual studio code and a directory with js in that visual studio. These js are triggers used in cosmos (pre/post).

Currently, after the changes, I manually copy the js and paste the changes in the cosmos trigger. I was thinking would there be a way of directly deploying the changes to the Azure Devops/Yaml Pipeline that as soon as the code changes are made in js directory, it gets build and changes get deployed and I don't need to manually copy paste the changes.

Answer (score 0):

Afaik, there is no direct way to deploy the changes to the pipeline but you need to edit the file manually in source control, pretty much the same way you would edit any other file.